# Django crispy forms - Set hidden field value

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I've got the following django crispy form:

```
class ConsultForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:

        model = Consults # Your User model
        fields = [ 'TEMPLATE','EMAIL', 'DATE']
        labels = {

        'EMAIL' : 'Your Email',
        'DATE' : 'Todays date',

        # 'captcha': "Enter captcha"

        }
    helper = FormHelper()

    helper.form_method = 'POST'
    helper.form_action = "/contact/"
    helper.form_id = 'form' # SET THIS OR BOOTSTRAP JS AND VAL.JS WILL NOT WORK


    helper.add_input(Submit('Submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-primary'))


    helper.layout = Layout(
        Field('TEMPLATE', type="hidden"),
        Field('DATE', type="hidden"))
```

I want to pass a value with the hidden field TEMPLATE. I've read https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_helpers.html ,     but can't see how to do this. How can I get this done?

Comment: what's the problem with your current code? What do you see?

Comment: The code is working, but I want to set the value of the hidden TEMPLATE field to "VALUE" when the form is submitted.

Comment: I don't know what "VALUE" is and where it comes from. You can set initial values to fields when initialising your form in your view: `form = ConsultForm(initial={'TEMPLATE': 'VALUE'})`, which will remain in the hidden input field and thus submitted. Or if it's a fixed value, in the form initialiser: `self.fields['TEMPLATE'].initial = 'VALUE'`

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to rely on hidden input values being posted to pass data from one view to the next. The reason is that anyone may change that value before posting. So only use this if it's convenient, not if it's critical to be correct. Or have some mechanisms to check that the submitted value still makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set Form field initial values like this:

```
class ConsultForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['TEMPLATE'] = 'my_initial_value'
```

You can also change the value of the field at other places in your code like:

```
form = ConsultForm(instance=instance)
form.initial['TEMPLATE'] = 'new_value'
```

With formhelper (with crispy Universal Layout Objects like Field) you set attributes as you already did, like:

```
Field('TEMPLATE', id="template", value="something" template="my-template.html")
```

If that's what you were asking for.

Or if the above does not work easy then there is a layout object called **Hidden** in crispy. You can create hidden input fields with that:

```
Hidden('name', 'value')
```

You use it as `Hidden('TEMPLATE', 'mysomethingvalue')`

Like:

```
Button('name', 'value')
```

To make it fully clear:

```
helper.layout = Layout(
        Hidden('TEMPLATE', 'myvalue'),
        Hidden('DATE', 'anydate'))
```

Comment: This is great but is there a way to set it with the form helper. I'm  not using the form directly in my code.

Comment: @user61629 - I updated my answer, but I am not sure if that's what you were asking for.

Comment: Thanks very much, that Hidden field is great! I see that it does not need to be declared in the Model or Form definition.